# ISO - not getting appropriate response

Tags: iso, iso8583, jpos

I have used JPOS library for creating ISO message but I am not getting any response, The call which I have initiated is SIGN-ON. The code which i have implemented and request is mentioned below.

length 42
0x0000:  4500 005e 4448 4000 4006 8842 0a14 5140  E..^DH@.@..B..Q@
0x0010:  0a5f 085d 952e 30c8 5cdb c683 49e6 692d  ._.]..0....I.i-
0x0020:  8018 01f6 6e60 0000 0101 080a 0775 0600  ....n`.......u..
0x0030:  889f a492 3038 3030 8220 0100 0000 0000  ....0800........
0x0040:  0400 0000 0000 0000 3132 3234 3139 3035  ........12241905
0x0050:  3136 3132 3033 3437 3030 3130 3033       16120347001003

````
channel.setHost("xx.xx.xx.xx", xxxxx);
       channel.connect();
       ISOMsg isoMsg = new ISOMsg();
       isoMsg.setPackager(packager);
       isoMsg.setMTI("0800");
       isoMsg.set(7, "1224190516");
       isoMsg.set(11, "120347");
       isoMsg.set(24, "001");
       isoMsg.set(70, "003");
       byte[] send_PackedRequestData = isoMsg.pack();
channel.send(send_PackedRequestData);```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For once, you have to set the packager to the channel and send the `isoMsg` object not the bytes:

```java
channel.setPackager(packager);
...
channel.send(isoMsg);
```

Additionally I don't see you calling `channel.receive()`;

And if you did there are many possible reasons why you wouldn't receive a response, among others:

- Unmatched channel/packager between client and server
- Server not responding for some internal error

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your respond on my question.. 

I have checked and applied same thing but still getting no response from third party.

Comment: then the third party has to tell you what they see, it's rare you get it working at the first trial, you need to carefuly align the packager and the channel

Comment: Hi, 

Just comunicated with 3rd party they are saying they will accept in ASCII format. 

Can you please guide me how will i send the data in ASCII format? even though i have tried new String(byteData) but still no luck.

Comment: Hi, I believe what remains is not a question for stack overflow, you need to read the [jPos programmers guide](http://jpos.org/doc/proguide-draft.pdf) to correctly understand what  packagers and channels do. Also, maybe starting with the [tutorials](http://www.jpos.org/tutorials) before that.

But it seems you need to use `iso87ascii.xml` as the generic packager configuration as a start an align the fields from there accordingly to the fields specifications from your third party

Comment: Sure, will read and get back to you. 

Moreover, I have already used this iso87ascii.xml file as the generic packager configuration. It would be highlighly appriciateable If you could come on call with me I will show you the code so that we can conclude this in efficient way. 

Thanks

Comment: Sorry this is not what stack overflow is it for, if you require jPOS consulting you may refer to www.jpos.org, also remember the license obligations, jPOS is open source but its license only allow you to use it with compatible licensing, meaning non-comercial use unless you open source your code under a compatible license too.

Comment: Okay I understand. 

can you please tell me how i send ascii data of 0800 message to ISO server? Can you please share some sample code?